# When using a popup modal for session timeouts, how can sensitive data be kept secure?

Tags: php, security, session, modal-dialog, timeout

When using a popup modal upon session timeout, is there a secure way to hide data previously injected onto the page through PHP? It has been pointed out to me that using an overlay that blurs the screen is not sufficiently secure since an unauthorized user could simply pick up from where the logged in user left off and inspect the html through any number of tools.

Is there any way to keep sensitive data secure in this situation while keeping the user on their current page when they are timed out? Redirecting the user to the general login page has been ruled out or else I would do that.

Comment: force a logout on timeout

Comment: I have a solution I can't share unfortunately, but the premise is simple.. I check if the user has not moved the mouse or clicked any keys in the past 10 minutes and then show a popup telling them they have 1 minute to click "I'm still here!". If they don't click within the 1 minute it will do a javascript location to my logout.php page. this page has everything I need to destroy sessions, cookies. On your main page just check if it has an active session, and force a redirect if they do not. this will prevent the use of the back button to get saved data after they log out

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking for a solution that does not take the user to a separate page when they are logged out.

Comment: instead of a location call, you would add your logout call to the timeout . I am using PHP sessions because my system needs to manage stuff regardless if JS is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if you can modify the page already loaded through PHP -- a language and context that runs *on the server*, **not** on the client.  The short answer, then, is no.  You can either (re)load an entirely new page, or you must use Javascript/API calls to perform the details you want.

@Conceptz has already pointed out that you can invalidate all the cookies, etc., by redirecting to `logout.php`, but I believe you're asking for only the client side detail: how to clear the DOM until an appropriate action is taken.  Given that, your solution will involve *client side* help, in the form of Javascript.

To actually answer the question, then, the quick, dirty, and unprofessional approach is the moral equivalent of

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

That is the nuke-it-from-orbit approach, but would work.  Anything less drastic than that will require you to iterate through all your sensitive DOM elements and replace the content with dummy or fake content.  Again, all *client side*, with *Javascript*.  No PHP.

If you absolutely must use PHP, an option is to get the updated and empty snippets of HTML from the server with API calls, and use the responses to replace the sensitive data, but again, that *still* uses Javascript to make the calls, and *still* uses Javascript to replace the actual DOM elements.

If you decide to do the clearing/replacing in Javascript (to avoid a page reload), then don't forget about your the variables from which all of your DOM edits originally came -- depending on attacker motivation, JS variables are a brilliant method for getting sensitive data.  For each sensitive variable and data structure, you'll need to do the moral equivalent of:

```
sensitive_variable = null;
```

All that said, if you're using a modern-day framework with data-binding, the "Clear all sensitive DOM elements" could be omitted entirely if you just update or clear the sensitive JS variables.